# regular expressions to match user input string as it is typed

Tags: regex, autocomplete

Is there a different way of constructing a regex like this...

`/^52\s*quarts(\s*\,*\s*|\s+)motor oil(\s*\,*\s*|\s+)las vegas(\s*\,*\s*|\s+)nv/i`

...such that the matches it returns for **"52 quarts motor oil las vega"** would be **["52 quarts motor oil las vega"]**?

I'm trying to add cacheing to a use of jQuery autocomplete, and I'd like to match user-input dynamically against a prepared list of regular expressions. As I need the matching expressions to be prepared in advance, they cannot fail to match just because they are longer than the completed user input string!

Comment: wrong approach - use a text-based nosql database like lucene that allows you to search for words within text in milliseconds

Comment: ok, but I want this hack, first.

Answer (score 0):

I have simplified your regex:

```
/^52[\s,]*quarts[\s,]*motor oil[\s,]*las vegas[\s,]*nv/i
```

if you wanted to allow words in any order, you could use look aheads:

```
/^(?=.*52)(?=.*quarts)(?=.*motor oil)(?=.*las vegas)(?=.*nv)/i
```

this look-ahead idea is pretty close to the way a text-based search engine would work

#### Edit:

Partial matches become a little ugly. Here's how you match on any *part* of a word - in other words a "start with" match:

```
l(a(s( (v(e(g(a(s)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?
```

To require at least "las ve", do this:

```
las ve(g(a(s)?)?)?
```

It's pretty gross. but there it is.
You could do this with all the terms.

Comment: Well, that does some work. From this string **"las vegas nv motor oil 52 quarts"**, it gets me an identical match. However, your regex does not match my original test string, **"52 quarts motor oil las vega"**, which was my basic need.

Comment: @Lille That's because you've left off the "s" from "Las Vegas". If you literally want to match "Las Vega", change "vegas" to "vega" in my regex.

Comment: but that's the point: can a regex be made to partially match ? So, I want 'vegas' in your regex, because 'vegan' in the string would be wrong (sorry folks) while 'vega' in the string should still match! BTW - I don't think regex is up to this challenge.

Comment: @Lille See edit to answer. You are right though; we're starting to scrape the barrel with regex